# mandatory fields of a transaction from JIRA rest APIs

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

How to get the required/mandatory fields while doing  a transaction in `JIRA` .

I have tried the below API but it is not returning any field id ..

https://ourCompany.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/" + ticketID
                            + "/transitions?expand=transitions.fields"

in the returning `JSON` all the value of `required` are coming false for all the fields(system and custom both) 
even if i have some mandatory fields in the form for a transaction.

Comment: You should try posting to Atlassian Answers: https://answers.atlassian.com/

Comment: I tried but no answers there as well

Answer (score 1):

You need the metadata information of the issue. Read this:  https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-discovering-meta-data-for-creating-issues

Note: you'll need the project and the issue type for the call, as the field configuration can be per project + per issuetype configured.